# Python 3.6 BeautifulSoup printing blank area after loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, beautifulsoup

I'm using the 'three-sisters' HTML on the beautifulsoup page (posted below this paragraph). I'm new at beautiful soup and I cannot, for the life of me, get this loop to output information that I can use in a `for/in` loop. I can get the names to print out alone, but I cannot get them to act as variables.

```
<pre>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            The Dormouse's story
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <b></b>
        <p class="title">
            <b>
                The Dormouse's story
            </b>
        </p>
        <p class="story">
            Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
            <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">
                Elsie
            </a>
            ,
            <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">
                Lacie
            </a>
                and
            <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link2">
                Tillie
            </a>
                ; and they lived at the bottom of a well.
        </p>
        <p class="story">
            <b>
                The End
            </b>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
</pre>
```

I'm thinking that is because they are not just "Elsie" (or whatever name I pick) or they are not technically a string. Here is the code, and I get nothing but a blank space in pycharm and then Process finished with exit code 0. So no errors...

How do I find out what is going on? Or how do I turn the output into just a string of the names after looping over it?

#### Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main_file_open():
    file = open('three-sisters.html')
    data = file.read()
    file.close()
    return data

soup = BeautifulSoup(main_file_open(),'lxml')

attr = {'class':'sister'}
father = soup.find_all('a',attrs=attr)

for child in father:
    if child == "Elsie":
        print(child)
```

The following appears in the "run" window of pycharm.

```
<blank space>
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Then it ouputs a blank, no errors, no nothing. So it's obviously not sensing "Elsie" within the string.

What I'm wanting to see is

```
Elsie
```

If I change it to:

```
 `if child != 'Elsie':`
```

then it outputs all three names:

```
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">
                Elsie
            </a>
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">
                Lacie
            </a>
<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link2">
                Tillie
            </a>
```

So I've been trying to figure out what is going on, because if I run into a circumstance where I want to only print certain "children" then how do I turn them from soup tags into strings so I can use them in for x in statements?

Like I said, I know I can get a "string" by doing print (child.string) but it doesn't turn it into a variable.

```
attr = {'class':'sister'}
father = soup.find_all('a',attrs=attr)

for child in father:
    print(child.string)
```

Produces:

```
            Elsie
        

            Lacie
        

            Tillie
```

Then if I do:

```
attr = {'class':'sister'}
father = soup.find_all('a',attrs=attr)

for child in father:
    print(child.string)

for child in father:
    if child == 'Elsie':
        print(child)
```

It still only prints:

```
            Elsie
        

            Lacie
        

            Tillie
```

Comment: What is three-sisters.html? Add the html in the code. Without the text, how do you expect us to help you? Also add your expected output.

Comment: Just posted it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Use `if child.text.strip() == 'Elsie':`

Comment: Thanks Keyur! That worked. Man, how do I figure this stuff out on my own? I tried strip and text everywhere.

Comment: @NickolasKent One of the benefits of Python is that you can run this code interactively, typically just by typing `python`, and entering the code line by line. Then you can use builtins like `dir(variable)` or `help(variable)` to inspect the object and see what you can do with it.

Comment: @StevenGraham thanks. I'll do some googling and check that out.

Answer (score 1):

If you check what you've got in `father`, you'll see this:

```
[<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">
                Elsie
            </a>, <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">
                Lacie
            </a>, <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link2">
                Tillie
            </a>]
```

The `find_all()` method returns a list of **tags** that match the given parameters. So, when you check `if child == "Elsie":`, you're comparing a string with the whole tag. Like:

```
if '<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">  Elsie </a>' == "Elsie":
```

So, even if the string `Elsie` is present in the tag, it will return `False`.

To check if the tag has the string you want, you can use the `.text` method, which will return "   Elsie   " (with the spaces and newlines). So you need to `strip()` it.

Finally, making those changes, you can use this:

```
for child in father:
    if child.text.strip() == 'Elsie':
        print(child)
```

Or, simply print the text like this:

```
for child in father:
    if child.text.strip() == 'Elsie':
        print(child.text.strip())
```

Comment: Aw man thanks so much Keyur for explaining it. I really want to understand WHY things are happening and not just copying stuff.

Comment: Since you are new on SO, please read this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).